# Haskell monad bind operator type

Tags: functional-programming

In Haskell, the Monads type class has the bind operator, which is represented by the symbol `>>=`

The type of such operator is:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Why does the function need to be `(a -> m b)`? Why functions the preserve che inner data type `(a -> m a)` are not allowed?

Has this choice been made for some convenience in the language design, or does it have some other reason?

Comment: 'a' and 'b' are arbitrary types, **and they are allowed to be equal** -- this definition is *more general* than what you are proposing.

Comment: Regarding the reason: yes, there are very important mathematical reasons why monads are the way they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a nice, and accessible, blog on why we need the type to have that form.

http://cdsmith.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/why-do-monads-matter/

Also, this blog *motivates* why we want them this why and how they naturally arise in our daily workings :)

Enjoy!

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your answer consists of little more than a link, which will make it useless, if that link goes dead. Ideally you would recap the most important statements from the linked article explicitly in your post.

Answer (score 4):

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

> Why does the function need to be (a -> m b)? Why functions the preserve che inner data type (a -> m a) are not allowed?

You seem to have missed a basic principle behind type variables: you are allowed to instantiate type variables however you please with concrete types, provided they satisfy the typeclass constraints (here, whatever you choose for `m` must be a `Monad`) and are all correctly kinded (`m` must have kind `* -> *` and `a` and `b` must have kind `*`).

So if you wanted to instantiate `(>>=)`, some possible choices are:

- `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`
- `(>>=) ::            [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]` (instantiating `m` to `[]`)
- `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m a) -> m a` (instantiating `b` to `a`)
- `(>>=) :: Monad m => m b -> (b -> m b) -> m b` (instantiating `b` to `a`... this is an equal type to the last one).
- `(>>=) :: Maybe Int -> (Int -> Maybe Int) -> Maybe Int`
- `(>>=) :: Maybe Char -> (Char -> Maybe Int) -> Maybe Int`

One last tidbit that can help understand the "shape" of the types for monad combinators. Look for types of the form `a -> m b` where `m` is a monad. These are called Kleisi arrows. If you were fanciful, you might imagine a different syntax for them, like `a ~> b` meaning "a function from `a` to `b` with side effects allowed by some monad `m`".

Looking at the type of bind, you see a raw `m a` type at the front. This is essentially the same as `() -> m a`: a function which takes "no inputs", and produces an `a` with side effects in `m`. The `m b` at the end is similar.

If we rewrite this type in terms of these Kleisi arrows, we get:

`(() -> m a) -> (a -> m b) -> (() -> m b)`

Rewriting using our 'fanciful' syntax above, it becomes a little clearer:

`(() ~> a) -> (a ~> b) -> (() ~> b)`

If you squint, this ends up looking like function composition: You start off with `()`, do something and get to `a` then do a second thing and get to `b`. Combining those two steps into one, we just start with `()` and get to `b` directly.